# Strange delay with RDS over MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I need some help or direction as to where to look for a strange problem related to our mysql on RDS.

We have two environments, one on EC2 with a local installation of Mysql and one RDS mysql instance. Both have similar hardware and have the same data.

in both cases we run the same stored procedure, both run from a third source (EC2 instance)

**On the EC2 instance**
With profiling enabled the query runs in 0.33 secs
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.33 sec)

### show profiles;

0.00012025   call crmDisplayDonorProfile(3139, 21)
0.000048     drop temporary table if exists tblProfile
0.022021     create temporary table if not exists donCodes (cd char(1))
0.0000755    delete from donCodes
0.000111     insert into donCodes (cd) values (substring(strParse,1, 1) ) 
0.0041805    drop temporary table donCodes
0.02201925   create temporary table if not exists donCodes (cd varchar(2)) 
0.00007275   delete from donCodes
0.0040465    drop temporary table donCodes
0.02208925   create temporary table if not exists donCodes (cd char(1))
0.0001155    delete from donCodes
0.00015625   insert into donCodes (cd) values (substring(strParse,1, 1) ) 
0.00342425   drop temporary table donCodes
0.02178325   create temporary table if not exists donCodes (cd varchar(2)) 
0.0001055    delete from donCodes
0.00390075   drop temporary table donCodes
0.00042475   select * from tblProfile

### 0.00571425   drop temporary table tblProfile

**On the RDS Instance**

### Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.84 sec)

0.00010275   call crmDisplayDonorProfile(3139, 36)
0.00006275   drop temporary table if exists tblProfile
0.02370575   create temporary table if not exists donCodes (cd char(1))
0.00007175   delete from donCodes
0.00010025   insert into donCodes (cd) values (substring(strParse,1, 1) ) 
0.0038815    drop temporary table donCodes
0.0226735    create temporary table if not exists donCodes (cd varchar(2)) 
0.00006475   delete from donCodes
0.00182825   drop temporary table donCodes
0.0253065    create temporary table if not exists donCodes (cd char(1))
0.0001185    delete from donCodes
0.00015075   insert into donCodes (cd) values (substring(strParse,1, 1) ) 
0.00297025   drop temporary table donCodes
0.0191115    create temporary table if not exists donCodes (cd varchar(2)) 
0.00009825   delete from donCodes
0.00280375   drop temporary table donCodes
0.0002995    select * from tblProfile

### 0.00460175   drop temporary table tblProfile

When I add up the queries from the profiling, the are basically the same.

So the question is where would the extra delay be coming from?

Any thoughts or directions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please get few more details from RDS web console, like read/write latency, Read/write IOPS, queue depth during peak time ?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to further look into your notion of "Similar Hardware".

Given that the local EC2 instance has ZERO latency, however RDS might have bit more of the latency; nevertheless that latency effect has wouldn't contribute to the slower query performance.

Can you re-compare these factors in your local EC2 MySQL vs RDS

1. Data Size ( Volume & Their Schema )
2. MySQL Versions
3. IOPS in the EC2 Instance vs the RDS
4. RDS Volume size ( Bigger Provisioned Storage would improve the I/O )
5. Multi AZ Setup for RDS ( would take further more additional overhead )

As it is speaking comparing your EC2 based locally run MySQL and RDS based MySQL is **`not` straight forward Apple to Apple to comparison**. It more like Comparing Green Apple and Regular (Red) Apple, both are apples but they are totally different fruits all together.

Comment: Thanks Naveen, I just wanted to point out that the queries were run from another computer and not on the instance the mysql was installed. They are thThey also have a youth Conference which people pay to attend (net zero revenue)
e same versions, IOPS is not set for either instances, I do not have Mutli-AZ configured. The data is the same in both instances, however I will re-compare to check. And the volume sizes are the same in both cases.